# Multi-Server Extended Events investigations

Tags: sql-server-2012, extended-events

Do you happen to know if there's a method of centralizing the Extended Events information of many servers in one place (for easier administration and diagnostic).

Ideally I would like to have something like this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2013/04/15/sql-2012-system-health-reporting-dashboard-visualizing-sp-server-diagnostics-results.aspx?CommentPosted=true

Only that it'll support Multi server environments and not a server/server  deployment.

Thanks in advance,
Roni.

Comment: There is ..but you have to roll out your own depending on what you want to collect. Be careful of what you are collecting as there are things that can severely affect server performance. You can correlate XEVENTS and DMVS to build a central performance repository. I remember Ola presenting it in PASS summit 2015.

Comment: Thanks.I looked for Ola's presentation online, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Ola's presentation (Building a Performance Monitoring System Using Extended Events and DMVs) is still available online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYNGUthp0mo (found it via http://www.sqlpass.org/Events/PASSSummit/BestofPASSSummit2015.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Data Collection and create custom collection items for each event that you want to capture. There's this small project called [Extended T-SQL Collector](http://extendedtsqlcollector.codeplex.com/) that can take care of collecting the data from Extended Events sessions and upload the events to a centralized MDW.

Here is an example of [monitoring blocking and deadlocking with Extended T-SQL Collector](http://spaghettidba.com/2014/12/12/monitoring-blocking-and-deadlocking-with-extended-t-sql-collector/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check your proposed links. 
It was a long shot anyway.